# Django aggregate with associated values

Tags: django, django-models

I have a models.py like so:

```
class ScoreCard(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    holes = models.IntegerField(
        default=9
    )
    handicap = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class UserProfile(User):
    ...

    def get_nine_stats(self, course):
       nine_stats = ScoreCard.objects.filter(course=course) \
            .filter(holes=9) \
            .aggregate(Avg('score'), Max('score'), Min('score'))
       return nine_stats
```

This is fine and returns almost what I need - a `dict` of max, min and avg. However, I really want those values with the associated `created` fields. Is this possible using the `aggregate` method?

Comment: Not possible using ORM. Imagine there's two max scores with different created timestamp, the ORM doesn't have a way to resolve which timestamp to use..

Comment: Right. Now that you point that out it makes sense.